# Is there a way to send parameters into a callback function without creating my own function first?

Tags: php, arrays, htmlspecialchars, array-map

I have an array of values that I would like to run through htmlspecialchars but with an argument such as this:

```
$param = htmlspecialchars($param, ENT_QUOTES);
```

The problem is, I have an array of values that I want to run htmlspecialchars on:

```
$array = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $array);
```

and I would like to know if there is a way to pass ENT_QUOTES into the array_map callback?

I can always use my own function that uses htmlspecialchars, but it would be nice if there was a way to do this already.

---

After the answer below, here is my end result:

```
$array = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $array, array_fill(0, count($array), ENT_QUOTES));
```

Which simply fills an array with as many values as $array has and it's filled with ENT_QUOTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you pass a second array as parameter to `array_map` that will contain as many `ENT_QUOTES` elements as your number of elements in `$array`:

```
$quote_style = ENT_QUOTES;
$array = array('"',"'","''''''''''''\"");
$ent_quotes_array = array($quote_style, $quote_style, $quote_style);
$array = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $array, $ent_quotes_array);
print_r($array);
```

Or, a little bit more elegant:

```
$array = array('"',"'","''''''''''''\"");
$ent_quotes_array = array_fill(0, sizeof($array), ENT_QUOTES);
$array = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $array, $ent_quotes_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my output helper function...

```
function change_values_for_encode_output(&$item, $key) {
    $item = htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES);
}

function encode_output_vars($vars) {
    if(is_array($vars)) {
        array_walk_recursive($vars, 'change_values_for_encode_output');
        return $vars;
    }
    else {
        $vars = htmlentities($vars, ENT_QUOTES);
                    return $vars;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for. As I mentioned, I was looking for a way to do this without creating a new function for the callback.